# Variable undefined inside a SASS import in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm trying to declare some *globals* for my rails project. Inside **app/assets/stylesheets** I created a **styles.css.scss** file, that looks like this:

```
$fullWidth: 900px;
@import "templates/navbar";
@import "templates/question-wrapper-main";
```

My **app/assets/stylesheets/templates/_navbar.scss** file looks like this:

```
.navbar-container {
    width: 100%;
    .navbar {
        width: $fullWidth;
        margin: 0 auto;

        .logo {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .navigation {
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

When I start my rails server, I get a:

```
Undefined variable: "$fullWidth"
```

Am I doing something wrong or sass variables only work inside the file they are declared?

Comment: try to force the loading order of the scss files. it seems that `_navbar.scss` is loaded before `styles.css.scss`

Comment: Did you remove the `*= require_tree` sprocket instuction in your `application.css`?

Comment: @DMKE, that did the job! Could you explain why?

Comment: Sure, I will form a proper answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour exisits because of two reasons:

1. Rails sets up Sprockets so that by default any stylesheet file under `app/assets/stylesheets` is loaded
2. SASS is smart enough not to double-load an already loaded stylesheet file.

While (2) is a desired behaviour, (1) sometimes is not. To disable it, you can remove the Sprockets instruction

```
/*
 *= require_tree
 */
```

from your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`. This instruction walks through your asset directory *recursively* (hence *tree*) and only obeys alphabetical order (as far as I know). This results in loading your `styles.css.scss` first, and *after* that your `templates/_navigation.css.scss`.

The SASS error is a result of that: the `style.css.scss` already references a then-unknown variable which is only defined afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `*= require_tree`  sprocket instruction, and required only `styles.css.scss` since all the imports for my css are in that file.

Comment: Tip: You could rename the `application.css` to `application.css.scss`, define a bunch of variables there, and finally `@import "styles";`.